# How to access the amazon linux ami from my ubuntu

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have created the amazon linux instance and now I have to config the instance using my ubuntu terminal via ssh. I followed the instructions given in the aws document but I am getting an error which says "permission denied" public key issue. I am newbie to ssh and also to the amazon web services kindly help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generated your key pair, you should have saved your private key to your local machine.  Once this is done, you SSH to your remote instance using the following command:

`ssh -i <path to private key file> ubuntu@<host>`

Your <host> will be the entry listed next to 'Public DNS' in the EC2 website.  It will look something like 'ec2-00-00-00-00.compute-X.amazonaws.com'

Answer (score 0):

Did you download the .pem file to

`$HOME/.ssh/SomeFileName.pem`

make sure it's permissions are correct

`chmod 400 $HOME/.ssh/SomeFileName.pem`

make sure that $HOME/.ssh has the correct permissions too

`chmod 700 $HOME/.ssh`

then try to connect *(use your own .pem filename and AWS hostname)* e.g.

`ssh -i SomeFileName.pem ec2-user@ec2-184-72-214-132.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

If this doesn't help then please edit your original message with the output of

`ssh -v -i SomeFileName.pem ec2-user@ec2-184-72-214-132.compute-1.amazonaws.com`